# What are these data type of characters?

Tags: c#, sql

[image]

I did a select statement in sql and 1 of the column return me this.
There is a need to query from that sql column, but as this is an existing system, I can only try and error.

From the characters, I have already confirmed if the numbers inside is 0015, I should get 15.
Problem is as you can see above, it contains more than one number, and I have to compare the numbers.

Using SQL Server and C# programming, can some1 guide me on how to retrieve these individual numbers in sql server as well as the data type in C#

Comment: "1 of the column return me this" what is "this"?

Comment: I just realise I cant see in here. Showed up in preview, will add in as image in a while

Comment: Guess I found this link which does exactly what I need for sql http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187323.aspx

But incase I need in C#, does anyone has any idea?

Comment: Can you give column name and type and the SQL for your select statement?

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you can directly assign ASCII codes to char. So, for instance, 
char c = (char)0x0041;

will assign character repesented by 0x0041, which in this case is 'A', directly to c. You can later convert to string, if necessary, by executing

string s = new string(c);